# Marionette events click. How to get attribute of clicked item?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

How can I get `value` attribute from `players.html` using Marionette's click event? I basically need to know which player was clicked. Here is my code:

**players.html**

```
{#myplayers}
<player class="standard" value="{player}" style="{style}"></player>
{/myplayers}
```

**players.js**

```
...

return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    model: new Models.Players(),
    template: 'tmp/players',
    events: {
        'click player': 'playerSelect'
    },
    initialize: function() {


    },
    playerSelect: function(e) {
        console.log('click test');

        // I need here value (attribute), of player that was clicked
    }
});

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inspect `e.currentTarget` in your event handler:

```
playerSelect: function(e) {
  var playerValue = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('value');
}
```

As an aside, `player` is not a known HTML tag or a valid name for a [custom element](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/). The HTML spec caters for unrecognised tags so your template will still be rendered, but it will be treated as an [unknown element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement).

If that isn't what you intended may want to use a standard [HTML5 tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element).